# pr2_arm_navigation_tutorials

Tags: ros, pr2-arm-navigation, environment, pr2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials

http://wiki.ros.org/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Making%20collision%20maps%20from%20self-filtered%20tilting%20laser%20data

In these tutorials, the pr2_arm_navigation package is being referenced, but I cannot find it anywhere. Where can I get it from? I am currently using indigo. I am trying to learn how to add objects to the planning environment to test planners with collision avoidance. If there is another tutorial with packages that are available, could you point me to them? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268327/pr2_arm_navigation_tutorials/) by [cornwallis](https://answers.ros.org/users/31479/cornwallis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried googling it? It's the first result.

Link: http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_arm_navigation

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cornwallis](https://answers.ros.org/users/31479/cornwallis/) on 2017-08-16**:
I have. The link on that page is dead.